# Pass message from a page to parent frame using Javascript and without HTML 5

Tags: javascript, frames, porthole.js

I have the following scenario where I have a page say “parentPage.html”, which contains an iFrame say “parentFrame” which hosts the page “childFrame.html”. “childFrame.html” contains another frame called “childFrame” and calls the page “sample.html”. Now, I want to send a message from “sample.html” and receive it at “parentPage.html” or “childFrame.html”.

I've tried using the [Porthole](http://ternarylabs.github.com/porthole/) library. However, it doesn't help me in solving this particular scenario. Also, please note that the above mentioned pages need no be in the same domain.

It would be great if you could let me know on how I can solve this particular problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this question actually involve jquery? You tagged it as such but never mention jquery in your question.

Comment: _" pages need no be in the same domain."_ - was this a typo that should've been "need _not_ be" or "need _to_ be"?

Comment: I tagged it under Jquery thinking that probably there can be some solution in Jquery. After all the fundamentals of Jquery is still JavaScript right?

Comment: Same domain, no problem, cross domain: Big trouble - look at CORS and JSONP. Why did porthole not work? Please give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around for this which is called crossframe technique please see the link to understand this technique http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/31/

Comment: That link is TOO old. The world has moved on in 5 years! You need a link that covers Fx 3.5+

Comment: @mplungjan can you possibly help me with what other ways we can do this

Comment: Does the porthole.js not do what you want? If not, why not?

Comment: @sushilbharwani - Thanks for the link. It works on IE8 but not on Firefox. Any ideas on what needs to be tweaked?

Answer (score 1):

Try run JavaScript as flows in `example.html`:

```
top.window.myVar = "my message content"; // parentPage.html will receive the message
```

or

```
parent.window.myVar = "my message"; // childFrame.html should receive the message
```

also, you can call functions in parent frame or top frame.

Comment: top===top.window - no need to do top.window - ditto parent – also does not work cross domain